# Insert Firebase token into my sql tables from Android

Tags: php, android, sql, firebase

I've been watching a tutorial that inserts the firebase token into the sql table.I'm trying to do to the same but code goes to `onErrorResponse`

I have done everything that the tutorial has and it's not working.From postman works fine but from my android phone isn't.Here is where the code goes.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


//URL to RegisterDevice.php
private static final String URL_REGISTER_DEVICE = "https://9.147.69.74/storeFcmToken.php";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

//storing token to mysql server
private void sendTokenToServer() {
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Registering Device...");
    progressDialog.show();

    final String token = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).getDeviceToken();
    final String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString();

    if (token == null) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Token not generated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_REGISTER_DEVICE,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        try {
                            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, obj.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) { //****CODE GOES HERE******
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("email", email);
                params.put("token", token);
                return params;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view == buttonRegister) {
        sendTokenToServer();
    }
}
}
```

here is my php file

```
   <?php

$token=$_POST['token'];
$email=$_POST['email'];

$con =new mysqli('localhost','root','','gekon');

$stmt= $con->prepare("INSERT INTO devices (email,token) VALUES ($email,?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ss",$email,$token);

$response=array();

if($stmt->execute()){
        $response['error']= false;
        $response['message']='token stooored';
        }
    else{
    $response['error']= true;
    $response['message']='token NOT stooored';
    }

echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: And what is the error you are getting?

Comment: @AndréKool the error.getmessage() returns null